# Change http:// OR https:// to //cdn

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm looking for a snippet of Javascript that fires up on page load and replaces all img src pointing to either http://www.domain.com OR https://www.domain.com with //cdn.domain.com.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: If you do that on page load, then all the images have already been loaded from the original location, so that seems completely pointless. Why do you want to change the sources?

Comment: You're correct - I hadn't thought it through properly!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do that on the server-side, but here goes:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('img').each(function(index, el) {
      $(el).attr('src', $(el).attr('src').replace(/https?\:\/\/www\.domain\.com/gi, '//cdn.domain.com'));
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: useless script, but good advice above.. no reason to use `cdn` after all image loaded)